# getting text to be horizontal as opposed to vertical

Tags: gimp, text

I just downloaded GIMP and am trying to work with text on a photo.  What I write appears vertically, how do I get it to display horizontally?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to GDSE.  Generally software support is off topic here, but we'd need more information to help. Could you post a screenshot perhaps? Also is it a Dynamic text box or Fixed text box? Have you tried other fonts? Which version of GIMP are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after poking around GIMP for awhile I've decided to stay with Photoshop for now.  May be back when I have more time to explore.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gimp 2.10 you are able to change the text to vertical by simply creating a new text box, adding text, then right-clicking on said text and at the bottom of the menu, you should see different options of aligning the text.

Comment: When I right click on said text I do not get any options for default text direction.